# String comparison is not working in php

Tags: php, string, if-statement

I'm very new to php. I have a json named `json`. When I try to do this:

```
echo $json->status;
```

I get :

```
CREATED
```

I try to compare this result with normal string `CREATED` like this:

```
if(strcasecmp("CREATED",$json->status))
{
    print_r("Order created successfuly");
}
```

but for some reason the `if condition` is not evaluting to `true`. Even though I compare `CREATED` with `CREATED`!

Not sure where the error is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to echo the length of both the strings too. may be that can give you some hint

Comment: What's wrong with if($json->status == "CREATED") ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This function return zero if strings are equal

```
if (strcasecmp("CREATED",$json->status) == 0)
```

Answer (score 5):

Look to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php):

`Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.`

so `strcasecmp('a','a')` is `0`, therefore you have to change your code into

```
if(strcasecmp("CREATED",$json->status) == 0)
{
    print_r("Order created successfuly");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php

Quote from the page :

> Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.

So `strcasecmp('CREATED', 'CREATED')` returns `0`. And `0` is not equals to `true`.
You must do that :

```
if (strcasecmp("CREATED",$json->status) === 0) {
    print_r("Order created successfuly");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (strcasecmp( $json->status, "CREATED") == 0) 
{
...
...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you just use a simpler if statement?

```
if( $json->status == "CREATED" ) {
    print_r("Order created successfuly");
}
```

And check for whitespaces at the end or start of the status.

Comment: `if (strtoupper($json->status) === 'CREATED')`. Also the answer doesn't matter as strcasecmp() should work too.

Answer (score 0):

To compare strings, try to do the following :

```
if($json->status == "CREATED")
{
   echo "Order created successfuly";
}
```

Comment: `if (strtoupper($json->status) === 'CREATED')`. Also the answer doesn't matter as strcasecmp() should work too.